# I lost my files when I tried to merge folders together

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I tried to merge to folders together and then accidentally clicked undo and now my files have just disappeared, they aren't in the bin or anywhere on my hard drive.

I'm trying Disk Drill and EaseUS but neither appear to be finding my files at the moment.

Comment: Simply recover the files from your backup disk (e.g. your Time Machine backup)!

Comment: I would if time machine was active and I don't know how to activate it